# django upload file to custom location

Tags: python, django, django-file-upload

Is it possible to upload a file in django using django's `model.FileField()` to a location that's not relative to `/media` ?. In my case upload an .html file to `myproject/templates`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot if I remember right, this kind of operation is in-secure. The file storage backend would warn it.
You could either customize the storage backend, or upload to directory like `/media/user_template` and set it in `TEMPLATE_DIRS`.

If you only want to use dynamic templates, check [django-dbtemplates](https://github.com/jezdez/django-dbtemplates) as a DB-based solution.

Answer (score 0):

try: `models.FileField(upload_to = '...')`

Comment: the value of upload_to gets appended to MEDIA_URL. So if i set upload_to='templates/' the actual path to this would me /media/templates.